# Poste method mongodb and HBS

Tags: mongodb, express, handlebars.js

I have a problem, my code does not work, it does not take the data I pass it

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  var photo = new Photo(req.body);

  photo.save()
    .then((data) => {
    res.send(data);

  }).catch((err) => {
    res.status(400).send('Unable to save Photo');
  });
});




<form action="/" method="POST">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Title Photo</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Title">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Photo</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="image" placeholder="Link Photo">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

with Postman I can send the data, but not with the form, what is the problem

use Express, Mongodb and Handlebars

please help me

Comment: How are you sending the data with Postman? As JSON Maybe? Forms send as urlencoded, so have you actually set up the bodyParser middleware for urlencoded content?

Comment: Also showing actual errors that **will** appear in your console is useful information which should be in the post. That's the "server" console and not the browser. Eyes off the browser since you're talking to the back end now.

Comment: are you using body-parser ?